# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on php and rested client

Tags: php

I have question about rested cliend and pdo. I want to take user info by single id and here is my code:

```
 require_once('index.php');
 $action=$_POST["action"];
 $id= $_POST["id"];
 switch ($action)
 {
      case 'GETCLIENTS':
           echo 'clientlar çekildi.';
           $stmt = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM users",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                echo $row['first_name']."-".$row['last_name']."<br />\n";
           }
      break;
      case 'GETCLIENT':
           echo 'client çekildi.';
           $stmt = $myPDO->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id."",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           foreach ($stmt as $row) {
                echo $row['first_name']."-".$row['last_name']."<br />\n";
           }
      break;
 }
```

But it says me Invalid argument supplied for foreach().. I tried for many time but i couldn't fix it. Can you please help me?

Comment: the query method return an object PDOStatement not array .

Comment: It seems your query if failing. To start, you should switch to a prepared statement with a bound variable to avoid non-numeric id- and sql injection problems.

Comment: Done. thanks solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this one in your case

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT name FROM users');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Getclients works perfectly. But ı want to take single user by id. I followed same way but i dont know why this error occurs.

Comment: like in your another case "GETCLIENT" you use where so here also you can use where and fetch only one record

Comment: replace the foreach with while loop as in my answer

Comment: Thanks but it appears another problem ...

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\service.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\webservice\service.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />

Comment: @sandy The returned `PDOStatement` implements `Traversable` so the loop itself is not the problem, the problem is that no `PDOStatement` is returned.